# How Delete Run Only Application from apex.oracle.com

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two application on apex.oracle.com, one is editable and another is run only. editable application can delete but run only application can not delete.I'm deleting run only application from apex.oracle.com but there is no option available.How I delete it?

Comment: It doesn't seem that we can use apex_instance_admin in AOC, either - it returns PLS-201 https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/REMOVE_APPLICATION-Procedure.htm#AEAPI2268

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute the following in SQL Workshop to restore the build status, allowing you to delete normally (as per Littlefoot's response).

```
begin
  apex_util.set_app_build_status(59895, 'RUN_AND_BUILD');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

- navigate to App Builder
- click the application icon (so that you'd "enter" into it)
- on the right hand side of the screen, you'll see the "About" section, and **Tasks** is just below it
- the first task is **Delete this application** - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is not possible when the application is run only.